# I am not getting the minimum value ,it showing 0, but in case of Math.max() it showing the right maximum value, why is it so?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not getting the minimum value and it shows 0 but in this case of Math.max(), it shows the right maximum value. Why is it so?

```js
function values(ar) {
  var min_val = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    min_val = Math.min(min_val,ar[i]);
  }
  document.write(min_val);
}
values([14,99, 10, 18,19, 11, 34]);
```

Comment: Because `0` is the lowest value--it's lower than all the values in the array.

Comment: Why are you doing all this? Just use `let min_val = Math.min(...ar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your expected behavior, in order to find the minimum, you want to start at the absolute maximum (Infinity).

````
    var min_val = Infinity;
    for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
         min_val = Math.min(min_val,ar[i]);
            }
document.write(min_val);
}
values([14,99, 10, 18,19, 11, 34]);```
````

This will write `Infinity` for empty arrays, or the minimum value for the input.

Answer (score 2):

It always returns 0 because you compare it to min_val.
Where min_val becomes the lowest value as 0 is lower then any value in the array. Therefor min_val will always be set equal to itself and stay 0.
Here is my fix :

```js
let ar =[14,99,10,18,19,11,34]
let min_val = Math.min(...ar)
console.log(min_val)
```

This is also more elegant than a for-loop.

Comment: Or just `let min_val = Math.min(...ar)` - no need to put it in an array

Comment: Right you are forgot to edit that out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Math.min()` receivec arguments like `Math.min(-2, -3, -1)` or with array `Math.min(...arr)`. You are giving these arguments `Math.min([14,99, 10, 18,19, 11, 34], 0)` where 0 is minimum. So you are receiving 0. Also, no need for a loop as `Math.min()`  finds the minimum. So, the solution would be:

```js
    function values(ar) {
        var min_val = Math.min(...ar);
        //document.write(min_val);
        return min_val
    }
    console.log(values([14,99, 10, 18,19, 11, 34]))
```

or (to match your case)

```
function values(ar) {
    var min_val = Math.min(...ar);
    
    document.write(min_val);
}
```

in shortest form:

```
document.write(Math.min(...ar));
```